# script.py in path but can't be executed without providing full path

Tags: python, path, macos-catalina, zshrc

I have a script I have downloaded and installed from GitHub that I am trying to add to my path. Although the script is in the path already somehow I can't run it unless I provide the full path.

```
echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
/Users/me/bin/SCRIPT_FOLDER/
/Library/TeX/texbin
/Users/me/bin/SCRIPT_FOLDER/script.py
```

Since I am working on Catalina 10.15.7, I saw in other answers that I need to add the script to the .zshrc file, so I did so.

```
code .zshrc
export PATH=/Users/me/bin/SCRIPT_FOLDER/:$PATH
export PATH=$PATH:/Users/me/bin/SCRIPT_FOLDER/script.py
```

Despite this the script cannot be run except if I type the entire path

```
python /Users/me/bin/SCRIPT_FOLDER/script.py --h
```

What can I try to solve this?

Comment: What script you used to run it?

Comment: it's from GitHub and it works well if I provide the full path but not if I just call it.

Comment: What command you used to run it? Did you use `python script.py`?

Comment: yes
python script.py --h
also script.py --h (in case). None works

Comment: Also if I do python script.py inside the folder where the script is it works fine too. So I know is a PATH problem.

Answer (score 0):

script.py must be executable and the first line must be as shown below.

```
? echo $PATH
.:./bin:...
? ls
bin
? ls -l bin/script.py
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 x x 40 Mar  9 10:54 bin/script.py
? cat bin/script.py
#!/usr/bin/python
print('Hello world')
? script.py
Hello world
?
```

If the script is not executable use the chmod command like so:

```
chmod 755 bin/script.py
```

Answer (score 0):

Like most command-line programs, Python doesn't consult your `PATH` for the arguments (e.g., `script.py`, given the command `python script.py`). Your `PATH` only matters when deciding how to resolve the command name (in this case, `python`). If `script.py` is in one of your `PATH` directories (like `/Users/me/bin/SCRIPT_FOLDER/`), it has the appropriate executable bit set, and it begins with an appropriate shebang line such as `#!/usr/bin/env python`, then you can run it with the command `script.py`.

Comment: Thanks !
It works in the sense that I can now call the script from anywhere but it doesn't really work because  it just gives me errors /usr/local/bin/script.py: line 23: import: command not found

Comment: @Amaranta_Remedios Sounds like a missing shebang line, causing the script to be read by the shell instead of Python.